# temp table connection owner postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, temp-tables

I haven't been able to find a function or query that would show me a PID that owns the connection.

these tables were created on the 20th and I haven't been able to find which open database connection owns it.

pg_temp_57.tmplb1604202242425
pg_temp_57.tmplb1604202239538
pg_temp_60.tmplb1604202242006

```
mainDB=# select relname,relcreatetime,relfrozenxid from pg_class where relname ~ 'tmplb16042022';
             relname              | relcreatetime | relfrozenxid
----------------------------------+---------------+--------------
 tmplb1604202242425               |    1461206562 |       372689
 tmplb1604202239538               |    1461206393 |       372487
 tmplb1604202242006               |    1461206520 |       372626
(6 rows)


[root@postgreDB]# date -d @1461206562
Wed Apr 20 22:42:42 EDT 2016

[root@postgreDB]# date -d @1461206520
Wed Apr 20 22:42:00 EDT 2016

[root@postgreDB]# date -d @1461206393
Wed Apr 20 22:39:53 EDT 2016

[root@postgreDB]# date -d @1461206562
Wed Apr 20 22:42:42 EDT 2016
```

Comment: socket that owns it = database session

Comment: Are there any open database connections dating back that far? Barring that, are there any prepared transactions open in pg_prepared_xacts?

Comment: There are and I kind have an Idea by comparing the PID and when the temp table was created but I wanted to know if Postgres would have an exact query or function that tells me